# onFormsSubmit(e)'s e is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

So I apologize if this is silly as I am new to google scripts and google forms.

I'd like to evaluate the field values that the users enter. I specifically do not wish to use the spreadsheet.

There is of course many postings on the net showing how to do this in principle. One uses either the "values" or the "namedValues" properties of "e" as passed to a function like:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){...}
```

However, if I do so, and fill and submit the form, e.values are undefined.

A simple

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  Logger.log(e.values);
  Logger.log(e.namedValues);
}
```

gives me

```
[19-01-20 11:16:10:564 CET] [object Object]
[19-01-20 11:16:10:565 CET] undefined
[19-01-20 11:16:10:566 CET] undefined
```

I am doing nothing fancy here, I just:
1) Create a form with one field
2) opened the script, added the function from above
3) connected the submit trigger to the function.

What am I missing?

Max

Comment: Read the documentation. Where did you find that there's `values` and `namedValues` provided in `e`?

Comment: Is your script bounded to a form or to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of the issue, can I ask you about the scopes in your project? If you can show them, please retrieve them File -> Project properties -> Scopes at the script editor. If ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms`` is not included in the scopes, for example, how about adding a comment line of ``// FormApp.getActiveForm()`` to your script? After put it, please install the trigger again. By this, this scope can be reflected. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example of passing a form to the server side code.gs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" method="get">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonOnClick()">
    </form>
    <script>
      function buttonOnClick() {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        google.script.run.doSomething(form);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in Code.gs

```
function doSomething(form) {
  Logger.log(form);
  Logger.log(form.fname);
  Logger.log(form.lname);
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I don't think this answers my question. I am implementing the form myself but use a google forms form.